# When an instance of a class is not created in the main method, will the default constructor be called?

Tags: java

When an instance of a class is not created in the main method, will the 
default constructor be called?

ex:

```
class A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("Hello")
    }
}
```

in this case, will the default constructor of A be called?

Comment: main is declared as static, so it happens at the class level, not the instance level. So no, it won't be called.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor is invoke when you create object. Main method is static so it is not needed to create object of A class so the constructor won't be invoked.

Below is situation when default constructor is invoked because you create an instance of A class. I create my own constructor just to know if the text inside of it is printed that's the proof that it is invoked

```
public class A {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a = new A();
       a.print();
   }

   public A()
   {
       System.out.println("Constructor invoked");
   }

   private void print()
   {
       System.out.println("Text printed");
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Constructor invoked
Text printed
```

Comment: In other words, `static` means “not object-oriented”.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your class `A` will only get called if you happen to create an object of your class using the keyword `new`, like in the statement below.

```
new A();
```

However, notice that `main` method is `static`. `static` area is also an object of the `java.lang.Class` class. So the constructor of the that class will be called.

```
/*
 * Constructor. Only the Java Virtual Machine creates Class
 * objects.
*/
private Class() {}
```

---

View the full source code,

- [java.lang: Class.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Class.java.html).